# Void Class in HashMap as a Value object

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap, void

I know the basic that a `HasMap` is a **Key-Value** pair but I want to have a HashMap with **keys only(No Values)**

I want to put  below java snippet in my complex method(i.e `HashMap` with only Keys and no value associated to those Keys). My requirement is that i am processing a `List` of Duplicate Records, and during comparisons, I am keeping only one identifier value(from group of duplicates) in a `HasMap` which I can later compare that whether the system has already processed it or not.

Here is the code snippet(gives Compile time error as Void class is uninstantiable).

```
Map<Integer,Void> map=new HashMap<Integer, Void>();

//Some Logic goes here

map.put("ss",new Void());
```

Any suggestion/help to have a HasMap only Keys with no value are welcome.

Comment: then why don't you use set

Comment: A HashMap with only Keys makes no sense in any way - use another Collection class that suits your use case (some Set for example)

Comment: Yes dear, though i changed my scenario but i would like to know if there is some way to add Void references in HashMap.

Comment: @ArunKumar - Void has a private constructor, so **No**, you can't. It is just used as a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would use a Set for such an issue, because there is no need to have a Key-Value structure when not using the value at all.

**Correct Solution**

```
    Set<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>();
    uniqueValues.add( "a" );
    uniqueValues.add( "a" );
    assert uniqueValues.size() == 1;
```

Note this is just for completeness I would always use a Set for your requirement and the rest is more for fun/learning/confuse people:

Since Void has a private constructor so you can not create an instance with the new Keyword.

However there are at least two possibilities to put something in your Map. 
Solution one is to add null as value. Because you do not need it anyway. And the second one would use reflection to ignore the private constructor of the Void class.

**HACK SOLUTION**

```
    Map<String, Void> map = new HashMap<String,Void>();

    Constructor<Void> constructor= (Constructor<Void>) Void.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Void voidObj = constructor.newInstance();

    map.put( "a", voidObj );
    map.put( "a", voidObj );
    assert map.size() == 1;
```

Comment: Thanks mszalbach! Yes the `Set` fits best collection in this requirement, but we should know the other side too(though its un-usable/nonsense or crime to use :) ) +1 for your Hack Solution!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want a list where you can add keys but it should not allow to add duplicate keys. Then the solution is to use a `Set`([Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)):

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

Java also provides a `Hashset`([Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html))

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

You may also need you own `Comparator`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use another list? If you really need to use a HashMap for whatever reason, you can just add null values instead of void.

```
Map<Integer,Object> map=new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

map.put("ss", null);
```

Comment: because this is a very bad solution that should not appear to be acceptable for future programmers that want to achieve the same thing as OP

Comment: OP wants a HashMap with no values, all the answers other than mine are not giving them what they want.

Comment: The reason not to use `null` as the value is that it makes the return value of `get()` ambiguous. For example, `map.get("thiskeyisnotpresent")` will return `null` because the key isn't present, but `map.get("ss")` will **also** return `null` because the key is present but is mapped to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not do this. A `HashMap` is a `Map` which is a Key-Value-pair. A `Map` without values is not a `Map`.

If you want to store values without duplicates use a `Set` - a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks Lion. Yes you are right as per usage of collection and there are few other collections are available for this scenario but i would like to know if there is some way to add Void references in `HashMap`

Comment: @ArunKumar There might be - but I see no reasonable argument to ever have a Map that is filled only with null/Void by definition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the constructor of `Void` class is *private*, so the compiler will mark `new Void()` as error. Next, to prevent duplicates, you could just use a `Set` . Why not go with `HashSet`?.

Here's what javadoc says about `Void` -->

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.